# Replace \ for " C#

Tags: c#, replace

Hi guys I need remplace this caracter \ change for ":

string example:

```
\"Yestin\":\"Number1\"
```

String Result:

```
"Yestin":"Number1"
```

Code Example:

```
String test= json.Replace("\"",'"');
```

Error: Cannon Convert from string for char

Code Example 2 :

```
String test= json.Replace("\"",""");
```

Error: Syntax Error ',' expected

Comment: Note that this looks like double encoded json (if it is actually a part of json string, not a full one), so you can try to double decode it instead of using potentially not correct replace.

Comment: As for replace you can try `json.Replace("\\\"","\"");` -  see [string escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `char` literal: `'"'`.  Which as the error states is not a `string` and you're trying to use it as a `string`.

This is a syntax error: `"""`.  Because string can't contain an un-escaped double quote.  Otherwise it looks like it's terminating the string, and there's an errant extra double quote.

It sounds like what you're looking for is this:

```
Replace("\\\"", "\"")
```

Notice how both the `\` and the `"` are escaped in each string literal.  This would replace instances of `\"` with instances of `"`.  You can also just replace `\` with nothing to achieve the same result:

```
Replace("\\", string.Empty)
```

Unless the full string has other instances of `\` that you don't want replaced, of course.

---

As an aside, it's worth noting that the variable name `json` implies that this is specifically encoded data, and this direct string manipulation *might not* be what you really want in the first place.  Depending on what you're trying to do, *deserializing* the JSON data may be cleaner.